# Data encryption based on user password

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

I'm developing an Android app which lets the user to store notes (like evernote, keep, and so on..) but with the capability to "protect" (lets say encrypt) some of those notes from being viewed by non-authorized users.

First of all i'll say that i have no idea in encryption, so any correction, suggestion, enhacement, etc.. its really welcome.

This is the scenario i want:

An user opens the app, log in with his own password, and then he can view those notes.

For all i've read about password checking, the best option its to hash+salt with a strong one-way encryption. However reading more about, i found BCrypt algorithm which seems to be better option. Also found [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) API for java, that looks very easy to use (i've to check android integration by the way...)

Which of those do you recommend?

If i use hash+salt, where i should store the (random) salt? Because ill need to append it to the user input password the next time the user login (then hash it) to check with the hashed stored in my DB.

That is one of the problems, the other comes with the data encryption itself.

My idea was to use the user password for the encryption, however that password would be short, so ill need another salt to prevent bruteforce attacks...

Any idea on this? Do you know a strong algorithm to encrypt some data (Strings) based on a secret key (user password + ¿salt?). Must be 2 way algorithm, to recover data decrypting.

And the last question: Is it safe to store password in memory (while user logged to decrypt data)? I've read much things, as Keystores and so, but no clue about the safest option here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to crypt some text ? If you didn't, you need to try. You will see that, output text is so big and complex. Everytime, There are some ways to decrypt your data but It's so hard to hacked by  a simple user :)

Comment: You store the salt together with the password hash (maybe in the DB). See: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm. You need the Salt only to prevent attacks if two of your user use the same password then they don't get the same hash.

Comment: i undestand storing salt in the DB would be secure for a scenario Server-Client, where DB its supposed to be also "secure". But on android, where de DB is in the "client", what keeps away to a hacker that gets access to my phone, to retrieve that salt from the DB and bruteforce my password appended to that salt? nice link by the way

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is for you to not work at such a low level. Encryption is **hard**, so unless you are planning on becoming a crypto expert, please use existing open source libraries that "do the right thing" for you, without you having to sweat all of these details. [SQLCipher for Android](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/) for databases and [IOCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/iocipher/) for BLOBs/files are two such examples.